# Error: Expected resource of type anim [ResourceType] While Apk Generation

Tags: android-studio, apk, android-animation

While generating signed apk I got this error, When I follow the error path and found the warnings in concerned class;

[image]

and concerned animation stlye under **drawable** is
[image]

searched the similar topics but mine looks like a bit different how to fix it ?

I moved my animation xmls  under anim directory and fixed in every class but then I got

> Error:(64) Error: Resources referenced from the manifest cannot vary by configuration (except for version qualifiers, e.g. -v21.) Found variation in tr [ManifestResource] 
>               android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

***Well I fixed my problem with moving animation xmls to "anim" directory from "drawable" the following error with facebook_app_id was about the sdk version, my partner compiled it on Api 22 mine was 23 and he warned a bit late. We fixed the facebook id problem with direclty typing to the Manifest still dont understand why it causes error when I call  it "@strings/..***

Comment: I don't understand - where are the `anim_slide_in_Left`, `bottom_up` etc... (the members that are marked in red wavy) defined? The XML you provided (should not be a screenshot, BTW) doesn't have them.

Comment: just wanted to show red underlines. R.drawable.anim_slide_in_left so they are under drawable